# ImageFailed is called when scrolling in listbox

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a listbox in which each item consists an image downloaded online.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Margin="10" >
            <RelativePanel>
                <Image ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding IMG1}" />
                    </Image.Source>
```

```
private void Image_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Image)sender).Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///assets/StoreLogo.png"));
}
```

and this is how I bind the data;

```
data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("item") select new Models.Item
{
    IMG1 = "https://example.png",
};

ItemsListBox.ItemsSource = data.Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault());
```

At first, it is working fine. However, when I start to scroll down and up again, all images get replaced by a default one as a result of ImageFailed method. So;

1. Why listbox tries to reload images when I scroll?
2. Why ImageFailed gets called even though image url is valid?
3. Do I have to cache images myself?

Comment: Please show the implementation of your IMG1 property, and also the Image_ImageFailed method.

Comment: I have added both.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the type of the `IMG1` property to `ImageSource` and set it like

```
IMG1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://example.png"))
```

Then remove the BitmapImage from XAML and bind the Image control's `Source` property directly:

```
<Image ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed" Source="{Binding IMG1}" />
```

---

Probably also force immediate query evaluation by calling `ToList()`:

```
ItemsListBox.ItemsSource = data.Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: same.. Anyway else to try to set a default image rather than ImageFailed method?